# Cannot find CSS menu in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress. I have created an account with WordPpress (but not yet purchased any plan). I have selected one theme and started editing it. 
Now I want to change the background color of Menu.

I have searched and found out that you can change it through CSS. 
as per [this](https://zellwk.com/blog/find-wordpress-css/) link CSS file can be found under *Appearance > Editor* but I am not able to find it.

[image]

I cannot event find it under Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS as I cannot see 'Additional CSS' menu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

look this screen shot

your menu css is depends on which theme you are selected, 
some theme provides the customization for changing the background color for menu
likewise i tried my wordpress site

Comment: I have selected 'Baskerville 2' theme. How do I know if particular theme supports customization through or not?

Comment: customization through css* or not?

Comment: am changed style.css

Comment: .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.active>a { border-bottom:2px solid transparent; background-color: #ff4d4d;}